# Concurrently running multiple tasks C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, task, multitasking

I have REST web API service in IIS which takes a collection of request objects. The user can enter more than 100 request objects.

I want to run this 100 request concurrently and then aggregate the result and send it back. This involves both I/O operation (calling to backend services for each request) and CPU bound operations (to compute few response elements)

Code snippet -

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
....

var taskArray = new Task<FlightInformation>[multiFlightStatusRequest.FlightRequests.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < multiFlightStatusRequest.FlightRequests.Count; i++)
{
    var z = i;
    taskArray[z] = Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        PerformLogic(multiFlightStatusRequest.FlightRequests[z],lite, fetchRouteByAnyLeg)
        );
}
Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
{
    flightInformations.Add(taskArray[i].Result);
}

public Object PerformLogic(Request,...)
{
    //multiple IO operations each depends on the outcome of the previous result
    //Computations after getting the result from all I/O operations
}
```

If i individually run the PerformLogic operation (for 1 object) it is taking 300 ms, now my requirement is when I run this PerformLogic() for 100 objects in a single request it should take around 2 secs.

PerformLogic() has the following steps - 1. Call a 3rd Party web service to get some details 2. Based on the details call another 3rd Party webservice 3. Collect the result from the webservice, apply few transformation

But with Task.run() it takes around 7 secs, I would like to know the best approach to handle concurrency and achieve the desired NFR of 2 secs.
I can see that at any point of time 7-8 threads are working concurrently

not sure if I can spawn 100 threads or tasks may be we can see some better performance. Please suggest an approach to handle this efficiently.

Comment: throwing more threads at it isn't going to solve the entire problem ; more threads does not mean it gets executed faster. in an optimal situation, your CPU can effectively run as many threads parallel as it has cores. if your system has 7 or 8 cores, you could roughly expect 7 or 8 concurrent threads before you stop seeing any performance benefits. try looking at the bottlenect in your `PerformLogic` operation and try to make that more efficient.

Comment: Your I/O operations sound expensive. you could also see limitations on the operating system level in the amount of cuncurrent network connections you are allowed to use. if they are less than the amount of cores you have, you will also lose the benefit of running those in parallel (since each task has to wait for a connection to become available)

Comment: Do you have any shared state? Where is computation itself?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing what is inside of `PerformLogic` method.

Comment: PerformLogic() has the following steps -
1. Call a 3rd Party webservice to get some details
2. Based on the details call another 3rd Party webservice
3. Collect the result from the webservice, apply few transformation

Answer (score 3):

Judging by this

```
public Object PerformLogic(Request,...)
{
  //multiple IO operations each depends on the outcome of the previous result
  //Computations after getting the result from all I/O operations
}
```

I'd wager that `PerformLogic` spends most its time waiting on the IO operations. If so, there's hope with `async`. You'll have to rewrite `PerformLogic`and maybe even the IO operations - `async` needs to be present in all levels, from the top to the bottom. But *if* you can do it, the result should be a lot faster.

Other than that - get faster hardware. If 8 cores take 7 seconds, then get 32 cores. It's pricey, but could still be cheaper than rewriting the code.

Comment: Might be shared state as well, actually. Especially hidden `lock`'s somewhere in a unexpected place.

Comment: To give more details for Vilx' answer: PerformLogic should be true async itself by using async IO methods. Then you can throw away Task.Run and your operations will run concurrently without being bound by the CPU.

Comment: @ckuri - True. But even then involving multiple CPUs might provide some small boost still. I'm not sure though on how to best go about it. Maybe the `Task.Run()` is still the proper approach.

Comment: I agree with the answer. The original code is a false async code, that won't be more efficient that mutlithreading (which is bad with I/O). Only if the method PerformLogic implements async fully allowing the compiler to split it into bits of tasks, you can take advantage of the async framework.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't reinvent the wheel. PLINQ is perfectly capable of doing stuff in parallel, there is no need for manual task handling or result merging.

If you want 100 tasks each taking 300ms done in 2 seconds, you need at least 15 parallel workers, *ignoring the cost of parallelization itself*.

```
var results = multiFlightStatusRequest.FlightRequests
                                      .AsParallel()
                                      .WithDegreeOfParallelism(15) 
                                      .Select(flightRequest => PerformLogic(flightRequest, lite, fetchRouteByAnyLeg)
                                      .ToList();
```

Now you have told PLinq to use 15 concurrent workers to work on your queue of tasks. Are you sure your machine is up to the task? You could put any number you want in there, that doesn't mean that your computer magically gets the power to do that.

Another option is to look at your `PerformLogic` method and optimize that. You call it 100 times, maybe it's worth optimizing.